# How to achieve next and previous keys like Reddit?

Tags: navigation, token

I am making an API and I have a list of products and I don't want to expose their indices / order to the end user.

I was thinking of doing something like what the Reddit API done (before they locked it) where you are given a "next" token and a "previous" token and if you want the next set of results you just pass in the "next" token and same for the previous.

Also I don't want any repetition.

I tried Googling it but I found nothing related to the topic (at least to what I found).